# 'Maven Java EE Configuration Problem' When Rrenaming a Certain Project

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

We are working with Eclipse 4.8.0.

I import a maven project with:
File -> Import -> General -> Projects from file folder or archive

When I try to rename the project I get:
resource  is out of sync with the filesystem
And the project is not renamed.
When I try to rename it again it works, but the pom.xml gives the following error:
'Maven Java EE Configuration Problem'.

When I save the pom.xml without changing anything the pom.xml is correct again.

Renaming the project again gives the same error.

Another project that I imported in the same way does not have these problems.

What could be the problem and how do I solve it?

Comment: I suggest you to use the Import > Existing maven project.
Also after importing select the project and run a refresh (right click, refresh).
Remember that when you do any change you need to perform a "Update project": right click on the project > maven > Update project (default hotkey is Alt+F5).
Hope this helps

Comment: Instead of writing the unmodified pom.xml 'right click on the project > maven > Update project' works also. But I find it strange that it is not necessary for the other project.

Comment: Import existing maven project works. There are still problems with renaming, but now the project gets the correct name and does not need to be renamed. ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using:
File -> Import -> General -> Projects

I need to use:
File -> Import -> Maven -> Existing Maven Projects

There is still a problem with renaming the project, but it is not necessary now, so no problem.

Maybe at a later time I should try to understand why one project has this problem and the other does not.

Answer (score 2):

For a maven project I would try with Refactor->Rename Maven Artifact.
That way, if you check the flag "Rename Eclipse Project into Workspace", you can modify the project name and the pom.xml at the same time

Comment: Works also, but just importing differently is better. ;-)